# Biographies of Kapalika's Mahasiddhas

Tags: guru, kapalika

While in the Vadrjayana (Buddhist) tradition we can find complete biographies like the one of Milarepa , Naropa and Tilopa and other Lamas, where can be found similar stories and biographies of Hindu Mahasiddhas like Sri Macchendra or relative to Kapailka's sect?